# Print the content from nested json in C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm in the process of learning C# and now trying to learn how to work with JSON objects. For the purpose of that I'm writing a quiz game. I have managed to console writeline the content of simple JSON objects, but when they are more complex I only can log the object name. Example is shown below in the code.

The JSON object:

```
{
    "QuestionId": "1",
    "QuestionString": "What is blue?",
    "Options": [
        {
            "Option": "The sky",
            "Correct": false
        },
        {
            "Option": "The limit",
            "Correct": false
        },
        {
             "Option": "A color",
             "Correct": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The class:

```
{
    public class OptionType
    { 
        public OptionType()
        {

        }
        public string Option { get; set; }
        public bool Correct { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public Question()
        {

        }
        public string QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionString { get; set; }
        public List<OptionType> Options { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\QuizGame\QuestionAnswer.json";

string jsonTxt = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        var json = r.ReadToEnd();
        jsonTxt = json.ToString();
    }

var question = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Question>(jsonTxt);

Console.WriteLine(question.Question) 
// prints "What is blue?" // works like a charm
Console.WriteLine(question.OptionType)
// prints "System.Generic.List`1[QuizGame.OptionType]"

// and if I do a foreach: 
foreach (object o in question.Options)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    } 
// prints QuizGame.OptionType x 3
```

My expected result is to be able to print the options for the question. It seems like at least something in the code is working since I'm able to see that there are 3 options for answer, so I guess it's something with my understanding of object oriented code / C# that is missing. Thankful for all replies.

---

**Solved:** I changed the "object" keyword to "var" (or "OptionType") and could then get to my nested objects. I've struggled for days with this. I googled and tried new things base on your input, so thanks alot!

```
foreach (var o in question.Options)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Option); // loops through "Options"
        Console.WriteLine(o.Correct); // loops through "Correct"
    }
```

Comment: read about `object.ToString`

Comment: To build on top of @Selvin's answer, what happens if you try to print `o.Option`? (instead of just `o`)?

Comment: @npinti it will not compile because  `object o` ... `var o` + `o.Option` should do the thing ... also *Console.WriteLine(question.OptionType)
// prints "System.Generic.List`1[QuizGame.OptionType]"* ... with this code is hard to belive that it's compile ...

Comment: the `Options` property is fine, only cannot be printed to the console as is. you wanna see its content, you have to serialize and then log it to console. Console.Writeline wouldn't print out a complex object's content just like that

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out a List. If you just want to print out all information then you maybe just want to add another foreach in your foreach-loop. Maybe sth. like this:

```
foreach (object o in question.Options)
{
    foreach (object ob in o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ob.ToString());
    } 
}
```

But there are better approaches for that. You could for example override the ToString()-Method in your model-class and just call question.ToString().